# Response data for the dynamic value in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Not able to get response data from dynamic values  for the correct requests,
i added debug sampler and also regular expression extractor still not able to get the correct response from the value i am getting same data for dynamic value , please can any one help me to resolve it.

Comment: add response and regular expression

Comment: Regular Expression: username =(.+?)&  response should very based on the user but here getting same response for all the users ex :members":[],"link":"https://dev.test.com/rest/items/Favourites","state":"NULL","type":"Group","name":"Favourites","label":"Favourites","tags":[],"groupNames":[]},{"link":"https://dev.test.com/rest/items/36_fueb9_Switch_L10","state":"ON","type":"Switch","name":"36_fueb9_Switch_L10","label":"L10","tags":["Lighting"],"groupNames":["string","GoodMorning"]},{"members":[],"link":"https://dev.test.com/rest/items/Away","state":"OFF","type":"Group" }